# wpf menuitem child item. How to set the color behind the drop-down

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

I have a menu that I've been asked to style so that the items have rounded corners... basically so that they look like buttons.

I want to change the black background behind the sub-menu so that it's transparent. White would be OK too.

This black isn't the border of the child item's buttons as I can set that to yellow and I see a slight yellow border but still see the black background.

I changed all the instances of black to purple as a test and still got this black background. So I can't tell where it's coming from.

Thanks.

[image: Menu Item screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! In order for the Popup's Border's background to be transparent you need to set AllowsTransparency="True" on the Popup element.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to restyle the menu. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082.aspx) is the example of how it's done by default. Look at the `Popup` in `<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" ...`, you'll need to replace it with your implementation. Perhaps you just need to remove `<Border Name="SubmenuBorder"...`, putting the `ScrollViewer` directly as a child of `Popup`.

Comment: I was just coming back to say that I found that this was the background SubmenuBorder. The only catch now is that I can set it to any color... but if I try to set it to transparent it shows as black. We're hoping it can be transparent so you can see the background of the screen beyind the rounded corners of the menu item.